# Ethereum stuck in the smart contract

Tags: contract-development, tokens, nft, contract-debugging, openzeppelin

I deployed a beta version of an NFT project, however, some people who were not in the whitelist got their eth stuck in the smart contract, now I need to refund them by withdrawing the eth in the smart contract since I do not have any money with me, yet I did not foresee any withdrawal function.

Are there any ways by looking at the smart contract source-code, to do a **front-run**, **delegation**, **self-destruct**, or any techniques to destroy the smart contract or send the eth to the deployer wallet?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
    
    contract NFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable, Pausable  {
      using Strings for uint256;
      string baseURI="";
      string private baseExtension = ".json";
      uint256 public _batch = 9456;
      bool public _firstwhitelist = true;
      bool public _allpeople = false;
      uint256 public _qtyperMint = 1; 
      uint256 public price = 0.001 ether;
      uint256 private supplycount = 0;
      address payable public _holderEth;
      uint256 public holderID = 0;
     
      address[] private allowedWhite1;
      address[] private HoldersBook; 
    
      constructor (address _addr, string memory _URI ) ERC721("Our token", "OTK") {
        _holderEth=payable(_addr);
        baseURI=_URI;
      }
        struct Holders {
        uint itemId;
        address owner;
        bool sold;
      }
    
      mapping(uint256 => Holders) private idToHolders;
      
      function ErraseListe1 ()public onlyOwner {
        delete allowedWhite1; 
      }
    
      function addallowedWhite1(address[] memory minteraddr) public onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i=0; i<minteraddr.length;i++){
            allowedWhite1.push(minteraddr[i]);
        }
           
      }
         function MinterIsAllowed1(address minteraddr) public view returns (bool) {
          for (
                uint256 allowedminter = 0;
                allowedminter < allowedWhite1.length;
                allowedminter++
            ) {
                if (allowedWhite1[allowedminter] == minteraddr) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        function IfMinted(address minteraddr) public view returns (bool) {
        for (
              uint256 allowedminter = 0;
              allowedminter < HoldersBook.length;
              allowedminter++
          ) {
              if (HoldersBook[allowedminter] == minteraddr) {
                  return true;
              }
          }
          return false;
      }
    
        function changeQtymint(uint256 _newqty) public onlyOwner returns(bool result){
           _qtyperMint=_newqty;
           return true;
        }
    
    
      function changeHolder(address _newaddr) public onlyOwner returns (bool)  { 
        _holderEth=payable(_newaddr);
        return true;
      }
    
      function changeUri(string memory _newUri) public onlyOwner returns (bool)  { 
        baseURI=_newUri;
        return true;
      }
    
      function changeWhitelist1() public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
       if(_firstwhitelist){
             _firstwhitelist=false;  
       } else if (!_firstwhitelist){
             _firstwhitelist=true;
            _allpeople=false;
       }
       return true;
      }
    
      function changeAllminting() public onlyOwner returns (bool)  { 
        _allpeople=true;
        _firstwhitelist=false;
        return true;
      }
    
     function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
      }
    
      function claim(uint256 _qty)public payable returns (bool result){
      
        require(_qty > 0 ,"cannot mint 0 NFT");
        require(_qty <= _qtyperMint,"Quantity more than 5");
        require(_batch > 0,"first drop is over");
        require(msg.value >= price * _qty,"unsufficiant funds");
    
        if (_firstwhitelist) {
            require(MinterIsAllowed1(msg.sender), "only people allowed can mint");
            require((balanceOf(msg.sender)) < _qtyperMint,"You cannot hold more than the limit set");
            uint256 supply = supplycount;  
            for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _qty; i++) {
              _safeMint(msg.sender, supply+i);
            }
            supplycount=supplycount+_qty;
            _holderEth.transfer(msg.value);
            _batch=_batch - _qty;
            if(!IfMinted(msg.sender)){
                 holderID++;
                uint256 itemId = holderID;
                idToHolders[itemId] =  Holders(
                  itemId,
                  msg.sender,
                  false  );
            }
            HoldersBook.push(msg.sender);
            return true;
        }
    
        else if (_allpeople) {
    
          uint256 supply = supplycount;  
          for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _qty; i++) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, supply+i);
          }
          supplycount=supplycount+_qty;
          _holderEth.transfer(msg.value);
          _batch=_batch - _qty;
    
          if(!IfMinted(msg.sender)){
                 holderID++;
                uint256 itemId = holderID;
                idToHolders[itemId] =  Holders(
                  itemId,
                  msg.sender,
                  false  );
            }
            HoldersBook.push(msg.sender);
          
          return true;
    
          }
          return false;
      }
    
      function getHolders()public view  returns(Holders[] memory){
        uint itemCount = holderID;
        uint currentIndex = 0;
    
        Holders[] memory items = new Holders[](itemCount);
        for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
          if (idToHolders[i + 1].sold == false) {
            uint currentId = i + 1;
            Holders storage currentItem = idToHolders[currentId];
            items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex += 1;
          }
        }
        return items;
    
      }
    
      function giveAway(address _addr, uint256 _qty)  public onlyOwner {
          uint256 supply = supplycount;  
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _qty; i++) {
          _safeMint(_addr, supply+i);
        }
        supplycount=supplycount+_qty;
        
      }
    
      function changePrice(uint256 _newPrice)  public onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        price=_newPrice;
        return true;
      }
    
      function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return price;
      }
    
        function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)public view virtual override returns (string memory)
      {
        require(_exists(tokenId),"ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");
        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension)) : "";
      }
    
      function pause() public onlyOwner {
            _pause();
        }
    
        function unpause() public onlyOwner {
            _unpause();
        }
    
        function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
            internal
            whenNotPaused
            override
        {
            super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
        }
    
        function transferFrom(
        address from, 
        address to, 
        uint256 tokenId
      ) public override {
    
        uint itemCount = holderID;
        for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
          if (idToHolders[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
              idToHolders[i + 1].owner = msg.sender;
              idToHolders[i + 1].sold = true;
          }
        }
         
         _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
      }
    
      function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
       ) public override {
    
        uint itemCount = holderID;
        for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
          if (idToHolders[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
              idToHolders[i + 1].owner = msg.sender;
              idToHolders[i + 1].sold = true;
          }
        }
         
         safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, '');
       }
    
      function safeTransferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory _data
      ) public override {
    
        uint itemCount = holderID;
        for (uint i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    
          if (idToHolders[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
              idToHolders[i + 1].owner = msg.sender;
              idToHolders[i + 1].sold = true;
              
          }
        }
         
        _safeTransfer(from, to, tokenId, _data);
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't see any way to get the Eth.

The only places where the code sends Eth is in `claim` when it sends the sent amount (sent inside that transaction) to someone, but it never sends more than the sent amount. So if there is Eth now inside the contract, I'm afraid it's stuck forever.

Comment: sad to hear that